# Can a 'UIButton' open a webpage in a 'UIWebView' that are in the same 'UIView'?

Tags: ipad, uiview, uiwebview, uibutton, push

I've been working on this project for iPhone/iPad devices, and after finishing the iPhone portion of my project I was struck my inspiration to change up the style of the iPad project.

My Scenario:

I have a View that has UIButtons in it that link to websites. Originally I planned that these buttons use a Push sequence to open separate View that already had a UIWebView in it to open the web page. But then I thought maybe I could use the UIButtons to open the desired webpages within the parent View.

My Question:

Is it possible to load a webpage using a UIButton, but in a UIWebView that is in the same View as the UIButton used to load the webpage?

Thanks in advance everybody, I think this should be possible but nothing is coming to mind at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course is possible (really... why not?). You just have a `UIView` that has a `UIWebView` and several `UIButton` subviews. Then you could do something like this:

```
// Suppose that self.mainView is the main container (and an IBOutlet)
// and self.webView is the UIWebView (also an IBOutlet)
// and of course your UIButtons (connected to IBActions)

-(IBAction)visitSiteA:(id)sender
{
    NSString *urlAddress = @”http://www.siteA.com”;

    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    //URL Request Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}

-(IBAction)visitSiteB:(id)sender
{
    NSString *urlAddress = @”http://www.siteB.com”;

    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    //URL Request Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Now if you don't use InterfaceBuilder you could just construct your webView and buttons in code and just add them to your mainView.

Finally if you plan to have a lot of buttons you could optimize the code by breaking the loading part into a separate method and just pass the url from your IBActions. Something like this:

```
-(void)loadUrlAddress:(NSString *)urlAddress
{
    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]; 

    //URL Request Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}

-(IBAction)visitSiteA:(id)sender
{
    [self loadUrlAddress:@"http://www.siteA.com"];
}
```

Comment: thanks bunches mate, knew it was something simple i was overlooking